# regex ___(?=[.]*)

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
___(?=[.]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ot6Bua/1

which matches this

[image]

whereas I want to match all _ _ _ but if there are 4 _ like for first one I want to match the 3 _ just before (

I can't find how with lookaround regex

Comment: Note that `[.]` can be written as `\.` and `(?=[.]*)` (same as `(?=[ABCDEF1233___#$%^]*)`, etc.) makes no sense as the purpose of a positive lookahead is to set a restriction on the match context, i.e. some pattern should match immediately on the right. When the lookahead pattern can match an empty string, no restriction is imposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the pattern `___(?=[.]*)` this part `(?=[.]*)` is always true as it asserts optional dots to the right. So it will match the first 3 underscores as the regex goes from left to right

You might assert either `(` `)` or `,` to the right instead:

```
___(?=[(),])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IAdzzo/1)

Another option to match the last 3 underscores is using a negated lookahead, first matching `___` and then assert not `_` to the right

```
___(?!_)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r7Yw9O/1)